# Most efficient way to check if any values from an array are false based on object map

Tags: javascript, optimization

I'm working with an object with keys that have one boolean value. I'm trying to figure the most efficient way to check if any values I receive from an array equal false in the object with their associated key.

For example I have an object like so:

```
cars = {
  bmw: true,
  lexus: true,
  audi: false,
  mercedes: false
}
```

Then I'll receive an array like:

```
allApproved(['bmw', 'audi'])  // should return false
allApproved(['bmw', 'lexus']) // should return true
```

If any of the values for the key `false` in the map, I want my function to return false. Doesn't matter how many, if any are false I want to return false. If they are all true, I will return true.

Comment: Definitely don't convert `cars` to an array. Using an object for direct lookups based on property names is both faster and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [***`Array#every`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The **`every()`** method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var cars = {
  bmw: true,
  lexus: true,
  audi: false,
  mercedes: false
};

function allApproved(arr) {
  return arr.every(function(el) {
    return cars[el];
  });
}

console.log(allApproved(['bmw', 'audi']));
console.log(allApproved(['bmw', 'lexus']));
```

Comment: You should probably mention that `every()` uses short-circuiting.

Comment: using `some` and `every` seem like inverses of each other, is one more efficient or are they a wash?

Comment: @Ben Then are identical in speed. One just looks for `false` and the other looks for `true`. I would use `every` to be more semantic.

Comment: Using `.every()` is more straightforward semantically. (I just rarely have a use for `.every()` so I naturally gravitated towards `.some()` when writing my answer, but in my opinion this way is "better".)

Answer (score 1):

```js
cars = {
  bmw: true,
  lexus: true,
  audi: false,
  mercedes: false
}

function allApproved(arr) {
  return !arr.some(function(v) { return !cars[v]; });
}

console.log(allApproved(['bmw', 'audi']));  // false
console.log(allApproved(['bmw', 'lexus', 'asd'])); // true
```

If there are not [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) elements in the array that don't have a corresponding `true` value then all are approved. (Noting that if `cars` doesn't have an entry for a particular brand then this code will treat that brand as `false`.)

Comment: I think `Array#some` is faster as it stops the iteration if any handler returns `false`.. Am I right ?

Comment: @Rayon No. `every` does that also. I wouldn't be surprised if one of the implementations was just a shell for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest would still be a regular old loop

```
function allApproved(arr) {
    for (var i=arr.length; i--;) {
        if (cars[arr[i]] === false) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Definitely fastest, but you probably want to say `if (!cars[arr[i]])` rather than `=== false`, in case one of the values in `arr` does not have an entry in `cars`. (Assuming unknown brands default to not approved.)

Comment: @nnnnnn -that's true, on the other hand it would check for any falsy value, not just the strict boolean `false`? Not sure what the OP needs, strict comparison to avoid falsy values, or non-strict comparison that works with empty values ?

Comment: The benefit of `!cars[arr[i]]` would be that if there was a `null` anywhere, it would also be falsy. Plus, it's shorter ;P

Comment: But is that a benefit, the OP clearly states that he's looking for keys with `false` as a value, not `null` ?